# A simple stochastic game

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, oc.optimization-and-control

An individual, henceforth called the *runner* starts at the center of an open two dimensional square $\Omega$ of side length $r \geq 2$.

At each turn, a vector $x \in S^1$ is chosen uniformly at random,  and the runner may choose to move one unit in the direction $x$ or $-x$ - that is, his new position is just his old position, translated by $x$ or $-x$. The runner’s goal is to stay within $\Omega$ for as long as possible.

Such a choice of moves by the runner is called an *admissible strategy*. Formally, denoting by $X_i$ the uniform choice of angles at each step, an admissible strategy is a sequence of $\{-1, 1\}$-valued random variables that is adapted to the natural filtration of the $X_i$.

Denote by $P_t$ the runner’s position at time $t$, and given a strategy $S$, define the exit time $\tau_S$ by

$$\tau_S := \inf \{t \in \mathbb Z_+ \, | \,P_t \in \Omega^c\}.$$

It is true, and not overly difficult to prove that given any strategy $S$, $\tau_S$ is finite almost surely.

An *optimal strategy* is one that maximises the expected time to exit - that is, $S_0$ is optimal if

$$\mathbb E[\tau_{S_0}] = \sup_{S} \mathbb E[\tau_S],$$

where the supremum is taken over all admissible strategies $S$. By compactness there exists at least an optimal strategy.

**Question:** What is an optimal strategy for the runner to use?

Comment: I guess if your shape is a circle, optimal strategy is the one to minimize distance from the center. (For a circle, by symmetry distance from center is all that matters, and there has to be some monotonicity/coupling argument implying that choosing smaller distance is always best.)

For a square my feeling is that the geometry is going to make things horrible to deal with. A crazy conjecture is that minimizing $L^1$ distance from the center is optimal, but I doubt this is true (probably slightly higher $L^1$ distance along edge is better than slightly lower $L^1$ distance in a corner).

Comment: @RonniePavlov Yes in the case of the circle, there is only the distance from the center as the sole invariant we need to care about. I was thinking that the expected  number of moves to exit from being $r$ distance away from the center (given an optimal strategy) should be monotone decreasing in $r$, and hence the optimal move is always to go toward the center, or minimise distance from it rather. That said, I am uncertain as to whether it’s actually monotone for all $r$…

Comment: Anyhow, in the case of a square, we now have two (symmetric) parameters to worry about - vertical and horizontal distance from the center.

Comment: This is a bit naive, but maybe you can turn it into something useful. You can iteratively define regions $S_k$ where some $k$ vectors in a row could force you to exit. $S_1$ is all centers of line segments of length 2 with endpoints outside square, which seems to just be a quarter disc of radius 1 in each corner. Then $S_2$ is all centers of segments of length 2 with endpoints in $S_1$ or outside square, etc. One strategy is to minimize the index of the $S_i$ you enter. I think it optimizes something, but probably not expected exit time. It should coincide with optimal for circles at least.

Comment: Because it took me a moment to convince myself: the finiteness argument is that there's a $\epsilon$ such that for any position $P$ of the runner, a positive fraction of movement vectors $x$ have both $P+x$ and $P-x$ at least $\epsilon$ further from the origin than $P$, and therefore for any distance $d$ a positive probability of getting a sequence of moves (of length $\lceil d/\epsilon\rceil$) that force the runner to distance $d$ from the center.

Comment: Do we know if the supremum is always finite? In particular, if the supremum were infinite for circles, then it would also be infinite for large enough squares using the same strategy.

Comment: @Steve Yes, it is finite using the reasoning suggested by Steven Stadnicki in the above comment. Namely you can bound the expectation by that of a geometrically distributed random variable.

Comment: (1) Surely the optimal strategy is myopic (i.e. only depends on the current point and not the history). (2) It also seems likely that there exists a function f(x,y), where x,y are horizontal,vertical displacement from the center, such that, given the choice between moving to points described by (x1,y1) or (x2,y2), the optimal choice is the point that minimizes f. Agree?

Comment: @usul Indeed, in fact we can prove these both by appealing to the so called “dynamic programming principle”. Such an $f$ exists in the explicit form $f(x, y) := -\mathbb \sup_{S} [\tau^{(x, y)}_S]$, where $S$ is a strategy, and $\tau^{(x, y)}_S$ denotes the exit time starting at $(x, y)$. Examining $f$ gives the myopic nature of the strategy.

Comment: Uh that should read $f(x, y) := -\sup_S \mathbb E[\tau_S^{x, y}]$.

Comment: Why do you say that a strategy is a sequence of random $\pm 1$ variables? An optimal strategy is deterministic, is not it?

Comment: @Fedor Petrov Hm, in this formulation, the strategy can depend on the previous moves, i.e. the choice of move at the $n$’th-step depends on the $X_1, \dots, X_n$. Thus it is itself a random variable since it is a function of random variables. The fact that it is adapted to the natural filtration of the $X_i$, however, means that it is “deterministic, once the previous moves are known”.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. So, we need a function from the set of pairs (current point, $\pm$ direction of the current step) to ($\pm 1$) which maximizes the expectation

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, actually there is a theorem that says that if a random variable is adapted to $X$, then it can be written as a deterministic measurable function of $X$. So the two formulations are identical.

Comment: I haven’t yet read carefully, but could you  confirm: A strategy should only depend on the position and on the  vector, right? I.e.  a function  $S:\Omega\times \mathbb S^1\to \{-1,1\}$ ?

Comment: @PietroMajer Yes this is correct. Probabilists would call this a “Markov strategy”.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer, just a comment, but I want my formula to display nicely - no need to upvote.*

So practically, you want to compute the unique function that satisfies
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
      1+\int_{\alpha=0}^\pi \min\begin{cases} f(x+\cos(\alpha),y+\sin(\alpha))\\
 f(x+\cos(\alpha+\pi),y+\sin(\alpha+\pi)) \end{cases} & |x|,|y|< r/2, \\
      0 & \max(|x|;|y|)\ge r/2.
   \end{cases}
$$

This reminds one not only of Markov-chains, but also of harmonic functions.
As the boundary conditions can make the function nasty, I propose to first determine the function for the disk, in which case the strategy is trivial, but I want to know the value of the expected number of steps.
By disk, I of course mean that the boundary condition is modified to give 0 when $x^2+y^2\ge r^2$.
This question already makes sense for any $r>\frac12$, just for $r<1$ the function will vanish outside some annulus of width $2r-1$.
I wonder from what $r$ will the maximum be at the origin.

Comment: My conjecture is that in the case of a disk with radius $r$, the expected number of steps is approximately $e^{r^2}$, up to a constant factor. Actually it’s more than a conjecture - I have a rough computation showing this is the case.