# How to play golf in one dimension?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, mathematical-modeling

One-dimensional golf is a function $g$ on $\mathbb R$ such that
$g(x)= 1+\min_\mu E[g(x+N(\mu,c\mu^2))]$ if $|x|>1$ and 0 if $|x|\le 1.$
Here $N$ is the normal distribution, whose mean $\mu$ you can choose in each step, but the deviation will depend on it, and on your talent $c$.

> What is $g$? Is there an explicit formula for it? Roughly how does it behave?

I set the dependence of the deviation as $\sigma^2=c\mu^2$, but other models might be more realistic.
Also note that I assumed the terrain to be flat.
The problem of course can be similarly defined in $\mathbb R^2$, in which case choosing the direction is obvious (if the terrain is flat), so the problem would reduce to the one-dimensional case, with a possibly different distribution function.
I wonder if this model is realistic to any extent, and how well it would fit on data from professional golf tournaments.
One would of course need to use different $c$'s, or even different distributions for different players.

My question has been inspired by [this question by Nate River](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431839/a-simple-stochastic-game) .

Comment: You will probably enjoy Gelman's and Nolan's foray into (2-d) golf. They wrote up the first part here http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/golf.pdf and added data here https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2019/03/21/new-golf-putting-data-and-a-new-golf-putting-model/ with further links there.

Comment: @Dror Great link, thank you! I have been trying to find other models of golf, but I couldn't. They also study one-dimensional golf, but only consider the probability of a putt, so ending the game from a given distance in one move. Their data seems to agree with the normal distribution model I proposed.

Comment: Haha, calling this process golf is so apt. Is there any direct relation to the planar survival problem I have in the linked post?

Comment: Based on the comments above, other people already seem to understand what the model is... :) Can someone write the description more clearly? What is a "step"? What are "$f$" and "$g$"? I'm guessing that you have a position $X_n$ at step $n$, then you choose a $\mu$, and you get a new position $X_{n+1}\sim N(X_n+\mu, c\mu^2)$. And you're trying to minimise (the expectation of?) something - the number of steps until you achieve $|X_n|\leq 1$? The recursion for $g$ seems to have a min over uncountably many r.vs. - maybe it needs something more like $g(x)=1+\min_\mu E g(x+N(\mu, c\mu^2))$?

Comment: @Nate I don't see any direct relation. It's more like the opposite of your question: we pick the direction, but we have no control over the step size.

Comment: @James Sorry, $f$ is the same as $g$, and the expectation sign was also missing - I fixed both.

Comment: @James Martin  Yes your interpretation is correct. With $X$ as you’ve defined, set $g(x) = \inf \mathbb E^x[ \tau]$, where $\tau := \inf\{n \geq 0 \, | \, |X_n| \leq 1\}$, $\mathbb E^x$ denotes the expectation operator under a probability measure such that $X_0 = x$, and the infimum is taken over all sequential choices of $\mu$ at each step. Then $g$ satisfies the given recursion by the dynamic programming principle argument.